# Cannot connect to remote MS SQL Server Express 2008 R2 from OLE DB

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, oledb, database-connection

I cannot connect to remote MS SQL server express 2008 R2. On the server, the external connection is enabled, firewall is turned off.
When my friend tried to connect using python, everything is OK.
I am using Visual C++ and OLE DB under VS 2010.

Error I get is:

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Thanks

Comment: What does your connection string look like (obviously minus the credentials and whatnot)?

Comment: Try connecting via server explorer in VS if you haven't already. If you're connected this will give a valid connection string. Also take a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/ if your struggling with your connection string.

Comment: when we tried to connect from the intranet, everything was OK. but from outside (only IP was different), we had the problem.

Comment: An example of your connection string would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to use Open method of CDataSource clas instead of OpenFromInitializationString..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use adodb connection, for example:

```
#import "C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll" no_namespace rename("EOF","rsEOF")

_ConnectionPtr m_conn;
_RecordsetPtr m_rs;
::CoInitialize(NULL);
try
{
  m_conn.CreateInstance("ADODB.Connection");
  CString conn="Driver={SQL Server};server=(127.0.0.1);uid=sa;database=pubs";
  if(FAILED(m_conn->Open((_bstr_t)conn,"","",-1)))
   {
      ::MessageBox(NULL,"connect database error","error",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
       return;
   }
 }

 m_rs.CreateInstance("ADODB.Recordset");
 CString strSql = "select * from Table";
 m_rs=m_conn->Execute((_bstr_t)strSql,NULL,adCmdText);
```

I hope this can avail for you